# Sending data to and getting data from node.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

In my React code I send a 'post' and 'get' request. My problems are in my server side code, I think.

**General**

```js
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cors());

const posts = [
    {
        "postId": 1,
        "id": 1,
        "title": "To be or not to be",
        "body": "Yes, that is the question"
    },
    {
        "postId": 1,
        "id": 2,
        "title": "So What?",
        "body": "What do you want"
    }
];
```

Note: Context, code above comes before the problem code

**Resolved 1) Post**

User clicks 'Submit' a post request sends data to server

**Problem:**

1) *The 'req.body' is empty*

```js
fetch("http://localhost:3001/create", {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(post)
    })
      .then(res => this.props.history.push('/posts'))
      .catch(err => this.setState({error: true}))

    this.setState({
      title: "",
      body: ""
    })
```

```
app.post('/create', (req, res, next)=>{
    // Request body is empty, why?
    console.log(req.body);
})
```

**Solution:**

POST request is sending data in JSON format because of `JSON.stringify(post)`, we need to parse this JSON data so we can use `app.use(bodyParser.json());`, and there we have it. SOLVED

**Resolved 2) Get**

In the first get request I am sending the 'id' of the object as URL params and trying to receive the corresponding object from the server, req is sent correctly.

**Problem:** Receive the following error in the 'findPostById' function:

*TypeError: Cannot read property id of undefined*

```js
fetch(`http://localhost:3001/posts/${this.props.match.params.id}`)
            .then(res=>res.json())
            .then(data=>this.setState({loadedPost: data}))
            .catch(err=>console.log(err))
```

```
app.get('/posts/:id', (req, res, next)=>{
    // Correct, receive id
    let id = req.params.id;

    findPostById(id, (post, err)=>{
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        else{
            res.send(post)
        }
    })
})

let findPostById = (id, cb)=>{
    console.log(id, 'Correctly receive the id');
    let post = posts.find((post)=>{
        return post.id === id;
    })
    // Receive: 'TypeError: Cannot read property id of undefined'
    console.log(post.id);
    if(post){
        cb(post, null);
    }
    else{
        cb(null, new Error('Could not find post', id));
    }
}
```

**Solution:**

`post.id` is type 'number' and id is of type 'string', return `post.id === id;` result in false because of strict equality. So, we convert id to number with `+id` `return post.id === +id;

Comment: Try renaming the key from 'body' to 'postdata' in the fetch request.

Comment: For 1) The error means that `post.id === id` is never `true` and thus `posts.find` returns `undefined`. There is not much we can do to help you here since we don't know what `posts` contains or what the value of `id` is.

Comment: As for 2), from the [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.body): *"`req.body` Contains key-value pairs of data submitted in the request body. By default, it is `undefined`, and is populated when you use body-parsing middleware such as `express.json()` or `express.urlencoded()`."* So it looks like you didn't setup the middleware correctly.

Comment: @FelixKling Yes, I did parse the 'req.body' using  body-parser library

Comment: @FelixKling Yes, the error is with `posts.find`... but what is the problem?

Comment: It could be a multitude of things: The array is emtpy, the array contains the wrong values, `id` is empty or has the wrong value or an object with that id simply doesn't exist in the array.

Comment: @FelixKling Ok, found the error for 1), post.id is type 'number' and id is of type 'string', `return post.id === id;` result in false because of strict equality

Comment: you can resolve the first error with  let id = +req.params.id; => id will be number

Comment: Can you add all code of your main file (index, app or server.js) in express app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For problem 1,

Please try to add this.

app.use(bodyParser.json());

Comment: I tried it does not work. The problem is I don't even receive data from the POST request, need to resolve this before we can worry about storing the data

Comment: Please try to add method-override.
const methodOverride = require('method-override'),
  // Request body parsing middleware should be above methodOverride
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
  app.use(bodyParser.json());

  app.use(methodOverride());

Comment: Did not need to convert posts to JSON, just needed to add `app.use(bodyParser.json());`

Answer (score 1):

Check if in your server side code is missing below configuration.

```
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "50mb" }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

body parser allows you to access req.body from within your routes